# Can't display VBO with simple cube, seems like issue with buffers

Tags: objective-c, ios, opengl-es, glkit

Trying to modify [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5223/beginning-opengl-es-2-0-with-glkit-part-1) OpenGL and GLKit tutorial at raywenderlich.com, I am trying to render a cube from a wavefront obj file, without the per vertex color information and with surface normals. But the thing that is rendered looks nothing like a cube.

[image: "(Not a) Cube"]

For parsing an obj file I have a method (createDrawable) that goes through the obj and saves the info into a struct (Drawable) that contains four things: vertex buffer, index buffer, number of faces in the object and the transform matrix of the object.
(Here are the [header](http://pastebin.com/J2ActMD4), [.m file](http://pastebin.com/7JQaSinV) and the [.obj file](http://pastebin.com/tWqLVzBZ).)

```
- (Drawable)createDrawable: (NSString *)objFileName {
    ......
    ......

    // Parsed obj and put info in vertexData and indices arrays.

    Drawable _drawable;

    _drawable.numFaces = numFaces;

    glGenBuffers(1, &_drawable.vertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _drawable.vertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertexData) * numFaces * 8, vertexData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glGenBuffers(1, &_drawable.indexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _drawable.indexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices) * numFaces * 3, indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    _drawable.matrix = GLKMatrix4Identity;
    _drawable.matrix = GLKMatrix4Translate(_drawable.matrix, 0.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f);

    return _drawable;
}
```

For rendering I am using another method (renderDrawable) that binds an object's buffers, sets pointers to them and then renders using glDrawElements(..).

```
- (void) renderDrawable: (Drawable)object {
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, object.vertexBuffer);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);        
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid *) 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid *) 3);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribNormal);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribNormal, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid *) 5);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, object.indexBuffer);
    glDrawElements(GL_LINES, sizeof(object.indexBuffer) * 3 * object.numFaces, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (const GLvoid *) object.indexBuffer);
}
```

I think I am doing something wrong with the buffers (part of createDrawable shown here and renderDrawable, in the .m file), but I just can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the "stride" param in glVertexArrayPointer should be set to 8 * sizeof(float) for instance (size of a single vertex)

```
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribNormal, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (const GLvoid *) 5);
```

when stride is 0 - that means attribs are stored in a continous way... but you have interleaved attribs so you must provide some more info to OpenGL.

Another issue: what is the `sizeof(vertexData) * numFaces * 8`... I think is should be: `sizeof(vertexData) * numFaces * 3`

And for index buffer: `sizeof(indices) * numFaces * 3` - I think it should be `sizeof(int) * numFaces * 3`

int - type for indices, but you have GL_BYTE (that means that you can have only 256 different indices!)

when rendering:
glDrawArrays - you have index buffer bound, so set the last param to NULL

Comment: `sizeof(vertexData) * numFaces * 8` meant providing the size of the whole vertexData array. It actually should have been `sizeof(vertexData) * numFaces * 8 * 3`, because there should be 3 vertices per face, and there are 8 float values (3V, 2T and 3N) per vertex. Using the latter makes more faces visible, though not for a cube. Also, I have changed the type of indices to uint.

Comment: yes yes... I wrote that answer to quickly and there were some errors :) Hope this helped

Comment: Of course it helped. It helped me take a fresh look at things. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

I think you problem is that you pass GL_LINES to glDrawElements() instead of GL_TRIANGLES.

Comment: No. Actually when passing GL_TRIANGLES, nothing comes up on the screen. I was just fed up and randomly making tweaks when I noticed that passing GL_LINES makes at least 'something' come up. (Ideally, the overall shape should be the same, I think)

Comment: No, the shape will be completeley different, because GL_LINES takes two vertices per line and GL_TRIANGLES three vertices per polygon.

Comment: Ok. I didn't know that. It means that nothing is drawn on screen when I am using GL_TRIANGLES.